# error TS2322: Type 'DeepPartial<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'

Tags: typescript, typeorm

The following typescript code

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm'

const save = async <T>(repo: Repository<T>, entities: T[]): Promise<T[]> => {
  return await repo.save(map((entity) => omit(['createdAt', 'updatedAt'], entity))(entities))
}
```

generates the following error

```
src/database/dao/user/user.dao.ts:46:3 - error TS2322: Type 'DeepPartial<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
Type 'DeepPartial<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'DeepPartial<T>'.
```

- typescript: 4.7.3
- typeorm: 0.2.45

I'm quite new to typescript and typeorm, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think that line is slightly wrong, it should be something like this:
`return await repo.save(map((entity) => omit(['createdAt', 'updatedAt'], entity),entities))`

Comment: If that doesn't work maybe try to do the map first, and then save it:
`let items = map((entity)=>omit(['createdAt', 'updatedAt'], entity), entities);`
`return await repo.save(items);`
To make debugging a bit easier